# In Goldeneye why did Ourumov turn traitor?

Tags: james-bond, goldeneye

In the James Bond film Goldeneye Ourumov is "top of the list" of potential traitors when the Goldeneye is stolen however M's analysts rule him out because

> He sees himself as the next iron man of Russia, which is why our analysts say he doesn't fit the profile of a traitor.

It turns out however that Ourumov is indeed a traitor and is colluding with

> Alec Trevelyan

Given it's so  unlikely that Ourumov turn traitor what was he offered to betray his country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as we know...(at least initially)

## For the money

Certainly Ourumov's motivations are *vague* at best and there is little clue in the movie itself.

The only comment in this direction is when Trevelyan says to him when questioned about Trevelyan's origins....

> "What's true is that in 48 hours, you and I will have more money than God"

Whether Ourumov had deeper plans than that is not covered.

As for the comment from M...

> He sees himself as the next iron man of Russia, which is why our analysts say he doesn't fit the profile of a traitor.

Bond's comment seems appropriate...

> Are these the same analysts who said that GoldenEye couldn't exist?
>
> Who said the helicopter posed no threat and wasn't worth following?

Basically, M's analysts were just plain *wrong*!

Comment: I had a look at this movie today and realized they got it quite right here. Ourumov has a lot of similarities with a particular Russian president (or maybe dictator is more accurate). I would not rule it out that Ourumov is a Putin portrait, which in that case would give the analysts right.

Comment: @patrik Are you for real? This movie was filmed in 1995.